# What Pathfinder Chronicles books are considered outdated, and what are considered still canon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, books

So, after the Pathfinder Roleplaying Game came out, Paizo shifted from Pathfinder Chronicles (3.5) to Pathfinder Campaign Setting.

I was wondering if anyone had a good list of books that have been completely outdated, semi-outdated, and not outdated at all. I'm also curious as to which books Paizo now considers part of the campaign setting. (I have a copy of the Pathfinder Chronicle *Dark Markets*, but the Additional Resources guide for PFS lists it as a Pathfinder Campaign supplement). I'm curious about this from both a mechanics and a lore perspective.

A couple examples I could think of that might help you understand:

- *The Inner Sea World Guide* has since completely replaced the *Pathfinder Chronicles Campaign Setting*.
- *The Great Beyond* (Chronicles) has not had (to my knowledge) a book published that replaces it completely.

Comment: This is a list question, which is normally not allowed, but this particular question is fine because the list is a fixed list of reasonable scope.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to set reasonable bounds, because I know open ended list questions are usually frowned upon here.

Answer (score 2):

The only things I could find that were 100% outdated are

Gods & Magic: Replacement Inner Sea Gods

Osirion Land of Pharaohs: Replacements Osirion Legacy of Pharaohs & People of the Sands

Adventures Armory: Replacement Ultimate Equipment

Comment: It's worth noting that Gods and Magic contains magic items associated with various gods that I don't think are reprinted elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but Inner Sea Gods do have magic items associated with the gods in that book. So you could say that the new items replaced the old.